# Multiple Logistic Regression analysis - what is the reason of very high delta AIC among models?

Tags: machine-learning, glm

I am dealing with salamanders biology and I am looking for the climatic and geomorphology variables best (sufficiently) explaining their presence/absence in the area. I have 1855 pixels with salamander presence and 104760 without their presence and my climatic and geomorphology variables cover all this area (all these pixels). I am applying Multiple Logistic Regression analysis in R based on glm(). The multicollinearity of my models seems to be acceptable (variables VIF<3) however the AIC values of my models are high (18272.47, 17576.52, 17391.83, 17087.87, 17026.07) and unfortunately the deltas AIC as well (61.79, 365.76, 550.44, 1246.40). I am more „salamander biologist“ than statistician.  Can I ask for any advice or recommendation?
Many thanks

Comment: Generally, you don't need to pay attention to the absolute values of AIC, only the deltas. The AIC values are the measure of relative quality. If you, as the expert salamander biologist, believe the models to be accurate representations of the system, the model with the lowest AIC is the most appropriate out of the suite of candidate models under consideration. Also, this may be better suited to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: hi @Roman, you have a total 1855 + 104760,thats a lot of data.Hence you have high AIC. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Hello Friends
Thank you to both of you.
I compiled a few sets of models. Subsequently I processed each set of models separately (no any collinear variables in any model, nearly all variables strongly significant). I expected the models averaging (deltaAIC<2) will be the suitable tool. However the differences in deltaAIC between all my models (not only between the first and the second one) were much bigger. This would be nice ... averaging is not necessary. The problem is, that such a difference appeared in all sets of my models regardless of variable composition.

Answer (score 2):

You have high AIC and delta AIC because you have a lot of observations.

AIC is only useful when you compare models for the same dataset. By itself, AIC doesn't mean anything. The formula for AIC (as from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion)) is:

> 2k - 2log(logLikelihood of Model), where k is the number of estimated
>   parameters.

So the more observations you have, the larger the logLik of the model. For example  (below the deviance is -2*logLik):

```
data = iris
data$Species = factor(ifelse(data$Species=="versicolor","v","o"))
fit_full = glm(Species ~ .,data=data,family="binomial")
summary(fit_full)[c("aic","deviance")]
$aic
[1] 155.0697

$deviance
[1] 145.0697
```

We fit on a subet of 50:

```
fit_50 = glm(Species ~ .,data[sample(nrow(data),50),],family="binomial")
summary(fit_50)[c("aic","deviance")]
$aic
[1] 106.369

$deviance
[1] 96.36902
```

One way you can check is doing an anova, `anova(fit_full,test="Chisq")` , to check whether any of your independent variables show a strong effect. Another thing you can do is see whether you are predicting the labels correctly:

```
pred_labels = ifelse(predict(fit_full,type="response")>0.5,"v","o")
confusionMatrix(table(pred_labels,data$Species))$overall
      Accuracy          Kappa  AccuracyLower  AccuracyUpper   AccuracyNull 
     0.7400000      0.3809524      0.6621433      0.8081242      0.6666667 
AccuracyPValue  McnemarPValue 
     0.0325328      0.1093146
```

Comment: Hello Friends
Thank you to both of you.
I compiled a few sets of models. Subsequently I processed each set of models separately (no any collinear variables in any model, nearly all variables strongly significant). I expected the models averaging (deltaAIC<2) will be the suitable tool. However the differences in deltaAIC between all my models (not only between the first and the second one) were much bigger. This would be nice ... averaging is not necessary. The problem is, that such a difference appeared in all sets of my models regardless of variable composition.

Comment: Hey @Roman, do understand from the above answer that AIC can vary different depending on the model and the number of observations, and is not indicative of a good model fit. If the models differ hugely on AIC, it means one is better than the order and you need to evaluate the fit

Comment: You can also check out this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78949/when-is-it-appropriate-to-select-models-by-minimising-the-aic?noredirect=1&lq=1, or just post your question on cross validated and maybe someone can explain this better than i can

Comment: Yes, I understand. I have already evaluated (75% train, 25% test) the fit of my models by AUC and McFaddenR2. Unfortunately no any better result than 0.8 (AUC) and 0.09 McFaddenR2.
By the way … the bonmonts in stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78949/… are really nice.

Comment: For a data of your size, AUC of 0.8 is more likely good enough. As you stated "I am looking for the climatic and geomorphology best (sufficiently) explaining their presence/absence". You are going to do inference, not prediction

Comment: As long as you are not overfitting your data (which I think you are not), i think the model is more or less enough to answer your question. Hey, all this is pretty abstract without seeing any data or output

Comment: Yes, of course.
Here is the link to (1) my variable dataset (CSV, 300MB), (2) text file with models and (3) photo of animal in focus:
https://www.uschovna.cz/zasilka/XB9NYI8LBS2HXG66-HLZ/ 

In salamander.csv:
„salamander$x“ … column with longitude in WGS84
„salamander$y“ … column with latitude in WGS84
„salamander$mloci“ … dependent variable with/without salamanders (mloci = salamanders in Czech language)